# Отложить, запретить прием POST NodeJs

Tags: node.js, post, api

К серверу пост запросом можно обращаться только админу (допустим) и к разным api - разный максимальный размер запроса. (можно грузить файлы или нет).

**Проблема**:

При запросе к серверу - ему нужно время, чтобы подумать (посмотреть что за api должна вызваться, проверить пермишины юзера... и тд), а запрос он начинает принимать сразу.... (я так думаю (или не так???)).

**Вопрос**:

Можно как-нибудь задержать прием поста, а потом или запретить его, или ограничить? Может нужно как-нибудь по другому разрулить эту ситуацию?

---

**П.С.** Фреймворки не использую и не планирую (пока :)

**П.С.С.** Буду рад любым советам.

Comment: А это действительно проблема?

Comment: Думаю да... можно же на сервак накинуть много запросов с большими фалами... и сервак ляжет

Comment: @myvzar, не говорите ерунды. Если вы не читаете тело POST запроса в node.js, то максимум, что вам грозит, это по полному буфферу чтения в readable stream на каждый переданный файл.

Comment: @myvzar, почитайте, как работают потоки в Node.js https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_buffering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде чем писать приложения на node.js нужно разобраться с тем, как работает протокол HTTP.

Алгоритм клиент-серверного взаимодействия имеет вид:

1. Устанавливается TCP соединение между клиентом и сервером.
2. Клиент передает серверу запрос вида:

   ```
   POST /api/resource HTTP/1.1
   Host: example.com
   Content-Type: application/json
   Content-Length: 14
   Accept: application/json
   Accept-Language: en-us
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)

   {"data":"asd"}
   ```
3. Сервер получает запрос и разбирает заголовочную часть.
4. В ряде случаев тело запроса разбирается сразу. Это зависит как от сервера, так и от типа запроса (существуют потоковые запросы).
5. Сервер отдает клиенту ответ вида:

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Last-Modified: Fri, 04 Mar 2016 01:16:26 GMT
   ETag: "10000000565a5-2c-3e94b66c2e680"
   Accept-Ranges: bytes
   Content-Length: 13
   Connection: close
   Content-Type: application/json

   {"done":true}
   ```
6. Сервер закрывает соединение или ждет следующего запроса клиента, если первый запрос был отправлен в keep-alive режиме.

Какие бы проверки вы не выполняли на сервере, ваш клиент все равно **будет ждать ответа**. И да, ответы с кодами `403`, `404`, `500` все равно подчиняются схеме выше.

---

Теперь вернемся к вашему вопросу и разберем, как node.js обрабатывает входящие запросы:

1. Обработка входящего TCP соединения происходит в ядре node.js.
2. Node.js  **полностью** считывает и обрабатывает заголовочной часть запроса и **инициализирует** readable поток для тела сообщения. (Ну и заодно writable поток для ответа.)
3. Вызывается функция обратного вызова, переданная в [`http.createServer`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener) (или подвязанная к событию [`request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request) объекта [http.Server](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server)).
4. Функция из п.3 что-то делает с запросом, и возвращает ответ.

Во всей этой схеме, единственное, что вы можете "*приостановить*" - это чтение тела запроса, но есть одно "но". На самом деле, тело запроса (readable поток) не читается, пока вы *не сделаете этого сами* в явном виде. (Да, в внутри потока есть буфферизация, но с ней вы ничего не сделаете.)

Чтение в явном виде может выглядеть вот так:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    req.read(function(chunk) {
        // Часть тела запроса доступна здесь.
    });
});
```

Если вам не нужно читать тело запроса, то просто *не читайте его*. Нет смысла что либо приостанавливать.

Comment: Спасибо! Хорошый ответ, но у меня есть еще вопрос... Я в input#file добавляю большой файл (2 - 3 гб) и отправляю постом. На сервере я ничего не принимаю (нет там req.read() и нет request.on('data',fn()) - в браузере я вижу процесс отправки... и он продолжается до полной загрузки файла. А когда я при получении запроса сделал (request.pause();) - Загрузка фала не продолжалась - она ждала request.resume();. Это как тогда?

Comment: Проверил с чистого листа... и Вы правы! Загрузка начинается только когда или сам принимаешь или когда отдаешь ответ назад...  Спасибо!

Comment: @myvzar, по идее, отдача ответа не должна влиять на чтение запроса. Это же совсем разные, не связанные потоки. А еще вы можете проверить на сервере размер памяти, потребляемой node.js при загрузке файла ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
http.createServer(function(request, response){
  request.pause();
  request.resume();
  request.end();
});
```

Это все что было нужно!

Comment: Это не имеет смысла. Если вы не читаете request, он не примет от клиента больше, чем позволяет внутренний буфер потока. Не нужны данные -- не читайте